# Young Adult Novel: Horse prince rebels, but then realizes he is the heir to the horse culture's savior prophecy?

Tags: story-identification

This was a young adult novel I read in maybe 1995 or 1996, and I remember little of the story except that it was about a horse prince whose horse culture had a savior prophecy to defeat their ultimate enemies that were some other supernatural creatures, maybe? The savior would be revealed by a black (or maybe brown) coat and a white blaze on the horses' forelock.

The main character starts out as a bit of a hot-headed rebel who thinks he can defeat the talking horses's enemy, but then some misadventures happen that I can't remember, and then the next season when he sheds his winter coat, he realizes he has the markings of the prophesized savior and then the book ends, or he helps defeat their enemies, I can't recall. It might have been part of a series? I always thought the name of the book was Cimarron, or something like that, but that is a *different* book about horses so I suspect I was conflating the two.

I tried to find this with the details I remember, and one option came up as similar but it was about unicorns and I'm pretty sure this was about regular (but talking) horses, and I haven't been able to find a copy of that book (Birth of The Firebringer) to confirm.

Comment: Birth of The Firebringer is available through [Google](http://books.google.com/books/about/Birth_of_the_Firebringer.html?id=AV2dY9DoPfkC) (ebook), [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/Birth-Firebringer-Trilogy-Meredith-Pierce/dp/0142500534/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1349460206&sr=1-1&keywords=0142500534) and [B&N](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/birth-of-the-firebringer-meredith-ann-pierce/1101327440?ean=9780142500538) (ebook and dead tree).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is [Birth of the Firebringer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0142500534). Jan (brown coat) is the main character and the prophecy refers to them regaining their ancestral lands from wyverns. A pilgrimage is made every year so that they can bath in a pool which will let him become a warrior. He is a rebel and his father the prince has denied him going before. But due to him going somewhere he is denied going he is able to battle a griffin that was about to attack his herd. This leads his dad to take him on the pilgrimage.

This book is very well written and doesn't mention the horns much. It mostly is a story of talking horses

I can go into more detail if you need but you do have the correct book.

Comment: Okay, good to know! I've never been able to find enough detail in reviews / summaries to know. I will track down a copy and relive my youth (ya right, I read YA fantasy like non-stop). Thank you!

Comment: I would definitely agree that it is *Birth of the Firebringer*. It is actually the first in a trilogy.